# Mongoose Model.FindOne and Model.Find with one query

Tags: mongoose, find, chaining

I'm doing a project for training. And I have this route

```
('/news/:category/:title', (req, res)
```

Here I want to pick up one particular article (I'm querying database by title - it's unique) which is in

```
 req.params.title
```

and the rest articles f.e 15 items.
How can I do that? Can I chain `findOne` and find somehow and render it in one view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
var findOne = Article.findOne({title: req.params.title});
var findAll = Article.find({});

Promise.all([findOne, findAll]).then(articles => { 
  console.log(articles); // articles[0] contains findOne result, articles[1] findAll
}, reason => {
  console.log(reason)    // if one of the promises rejected
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I needed!

Comment: Ok, but I have a question. What if some data from findAll is related to data from findOne and I need f.e author from articles[0] and take advantages of that in articles[1]?

Can I do that like this? (extremly poor example) 

`Promise.all(promises).then(return //somecode
     ).then(
     now I have access to the code above?
     )`

Comment: Yes, then you cannot run both queries in parallel. You're bound to run one first and the other after it. You'll need to run the promises sequentially as you hinted yourself.

Comment: Ok, ill try that.

Comment: Can I do it like that or I need to use Primise.all?
`Artice.findOne({
     title: req.params.title
}). then((articleData) => {
return Article.find({author: articleData.author})
}).then((authorArticles)=>{
res.redner('view',{
findOne: articleData,
find: authorArticles
})
}).catch((err))`